# Stored procedure terminating without giving error when executing from program

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Scenario:**

I have a stored procedure for student seat allotment and there are more than 8000 students being allotted using this stored procedure, and it is working fine when I am executing it from SQL Server 2014.

But when I am calling the same stored procedure from my .net program, it is terminating in the middle of execution. My stored procedure contains more than 500 of lines so I'm not putting its code here. But the .net code is as follows:

```
protected void btnAllotment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataClassesAdmission2015DataContext dc = new DataClassesAdmission2015DataContext();
        dc.Allotment(ChkReshuffle.Checked, ddlCriteria.SelectedItem.Text, ddlRound.SelectedItem.Text,null);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Allotment is done Successfully')</script>");
        dc.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Error at Alloment <br>" + ex.ToString() + "')</script>");    
    }
}
```

**Note:** I'm not getting any error here but store procedure terminating in background. So If any one have any suggestion or solution than please let me know.

Comment: You put very few details to allow us to find the problem. Are you sure your program is doing/opening the Connection? Is this "user" (the authenticated user where your code is running under) really authenticated to execute StoredProcedure?

Comment: Since you saying "... terminating in the middle of execution..." it can be related to the connection timeout of SQL or even the Query-Timeout settings of SQL...

Comment: Yes there is no issue related to connection or authentication it is working also for more than 500 students but after that is termineted without givinf any error

Comment: See the database settings for "Query Tiemout" or even the memory allocation threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it using `CommandTimeout` property. Actually When I was calling my stored procedure from dc object than it was taking around 15 minutes to complete its task. That's way I was unable to trace it because default `CommandTimeout` is 30 seconds as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

```
using(DataClassesAdmission2015DataContext dc = new DataClassesAdmission2015DataContext())
{
    dc.CommandTimeout = 60*60;
    dc.Allotment(ChkReshuffle.Checked, ddlCriteria.SelectedItem.Text, ddlRound.SelectedItem.Text, null);
}
```

Now it is working for me.